# PySpark: How to Convert UTC Timestamp Field to CST (US/Central) Keeping Timestamp Datatype

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp, timezone

I have the following sample data set below.  The column's datatype is timestamp

```
datetime_utc
2017-03-29T23:20:00Z
2017-04-17T19:00:00Z
```

I want to convert from UTC (coordinated universal time) to Central Standard Time (CST).  I know how to do this in Python Pandas but don't know how in Pyspark.

Comment: Do you have `hive` structure for the table having this `timestamp`? If yes, try to match with this approach (see timestamp columns and set `timestamp.formats` on that). https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/ql/src/test/queries/clientpositive/timestamp_formats.q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spark dataframe, you can use `from_utc_timestamp()` function to convert UTC to other timezones.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn('datetime_cst', F.from_utc_timestamp('datetime_utc', 'CST')).show()
```